# Make-File: compile multiple SRC-Folders to single OBJ-Folder

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, resources, precompile

I got a project hierarchy that looks like this:

```
+Makefile
+---src
|   main.c
|   ...
|   +---block
|   |       air.c
|   |       ...
|   |       
|   +---entity
|   |       esc.c
|   |       esc.h
|   |       ...
|   |       
|   \---world
|           \---gen
|                noise.c
|                ...
|           xyz.c
|           ...
\---obj
    main.o
    air.o
    esc.o
    noise.o
    xyz.o
    ...
```

I want to compile all the .c files in the hierarchy into one obj folder using make.
So far I got:

```
UNAME_S = $(shell uname -s)

CC = clang
CFLAGS = -std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wstrict-aliasing
CFLAGS += -Wno-pointer-arith -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-gnu-statement-expression
CFLAGS += -Wno-gnu-compound-literal-initializer -Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments
CFLAGS += -Ilib/cglm/include -Ilib/glad/include -Ilib/glfw/include -Ilib/stb -Ilib/noise -fbracket-depth=1024
LDFLAGS = lib/glad/src/glad.o lib/cglm/libcglm.a lib/glfw/src/libglfw3.a lib/noise/libnoise.a -lm

# GLFW required frameworks on OSX
ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Darwin)
    LDFLAGS += -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -framework Cocoa
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME_S), Linux)
    LDFLAGS += -ldl -lpthread
endif

OBJ_DIR = obj

SRC = $(wildcard src/**/*.c) $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/**/**/*.c) $(wildcard src/**/**/**/*.c)
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(notdir $(basename $(SRC)))))

SRC_DIRS = $(sort $(dir $(SRC)))
BIN = bin

.PHONY: all clean

all: dirs libs game

libs:
    cd lib/cglm && cmake . -DCGLM_STATIC=ON && make
    cd lib/glad && $(CC) -o src/glad.o -Iinclude -c src/glad.c
    cd lib/glfw && cmake . && make
    cd lib/noise && make

dirs:
    mkdir -p ./$(BIN) ./$(OBJ_DIR)

run: all
    $(BIN)/game

game: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $(BIN)/game $^ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/block/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/entity/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/gfx/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/ui/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/util/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/world/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: src/world/gen/%.c
    $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN) $(OBJ_DIR)
```

Is there any way to get this done in a more efficient way? Especially the $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o cases?

- Variable $(SRC_DIRS) stores all src folders
- Variable $(SRC) stores all .c files with their paths
- Variable $(OBJ) stores all .o file paths and names

Comment: `**` is not special to make's `wildcard` function.  `src/**/*.c` is identical `src/*/*.c` for example.

Comment: In general it's not a great idea to put all the object files into a single directory: badness will happen if you put source files named `foo.c` in two different source directories.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the same thing" happening.  What thing is that?  Clearly if you put object files in a different object directory for each source directory, then you can't get conflicts.

Comment: I used ** just as a reminder for myself that I mean folders, not files

Comment: It's impossible to have two source files with the same name in the same directory, right?  So, if every source file converts to an object file with the same directory structure, you can't have two object files that conflict.  That is, if you have `src/foo/bar.c` and you write out `obj/foo/bar.o` then that can't conflict with `src/blah/bar.c`, because that will turn into `obj/blah/bar.o` not `obj/foo/bar.o`.

Comment: But during linking src/foo/bar.c and src/blah/bar.c are combined resulting in the same problem as two obj files with the same name... doesn't it?

Comment: Well, obviously I'm assuming that `src/foo/bar.c` and `src/blah/bar.c` have different content and do different things.  For example maybe you're creating a tool that can connect to remote systems using either SSH or HTTP, then you might have two files like `src/ssh/connect.c` to connect via ssh, and `src/http/connect.c` to connect through SSH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is [using VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Directory-Search.html).

For example:

```
SRC := $(wildcard src/*/*.c) $(wildcard src/*.c) $(wildcard src/*/*/*.c) $(wildcard src/*/*/*/*.c)
OBJ := $(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(notdir $(basename $(SRC)))))

SRC_DIRS := $(sort $(dir $(SRC)))

VPATH := $(SRC_DIRS)

  ...

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)
```

You just need the one pattern rule.